# OSGiVersion incompatible with java.lang.String

Tags: eclipse, plugins

I have imported an already existing Plugin project and now I want to Export it and install it in host.
So i use File - Export - Deployable plug-ins and fragments - Install into host.

Last week all went fine and I could do the export.
These last days, i keep getting this error:

An internal error occurred during: "Install Job".
org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.OSGiVersion incompatible with java.lang.String

Any help/suggestion would be appreciated.

Exception stack trace:

Exception stack trace:  java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.OSGiVersion incompatible with java.lang.String
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.RequiredCapability.getNamespace(RequiredCapability.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.RequirementChange.matches(RequirementChange.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.director.Projector.mergeRequirements(Projector.java:934)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.director.Projector.expandRequirementsWithPatches(Projector.java:593)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.director.Projector.processIU(Projector.java:558)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.director.Projector.encode(Projector.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.director.SimplePlanner.getSolutionFor(SimplePlanner.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.director.SimplePlanner.getProvisioningPlan(SimplePlanner.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.operations.PlannerResolutionJob.runModal(PlannerResolutionJob.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations.ProfileChangeOperation.resolveModal(ProfileChangeOperation.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.ui.build.RuntimeInstallJob.run(RuntimeInstallJob.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)

Comment: The full stack trace of the error might help

Comment: Looks like Eclipse bug [377810](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=377810). Unfortunately this is still open and doesn't seem to have been worked on much.

Comment: Added the exception trace in the question above, as it is displayed in the Error log.

Comment: Seems to work in Eclipse Luna. But i really need this to work in my current Eclipse Juno.